# Can Cron jobs access password-protected directories?

Tags: php, cron, directory

I have a PHP script that I'm going to run with a Cron periodically to update some statuses. If I place the script in a directory that is password protected does the server still have access to execute the script?

If the script is in a password protected directory that requires http authentication - "username" "password", what cron command would I use to execute the script located here: "public_html/wp-content/stats/status.php"?

The script works fine if I access it over the web in my browser, and enter the htauth credentials.

Comment: If by "password protected" you mean protected by Basic HTTP authentication (.htaccess), then yes, this protection has nothing to do with accessing files directly on the server. Cronjob can access the files as long as user, under which it runs can access them.

Comment: @MiroDavid Thank you. Yes, I will be setting a password on the directory from the cpanel file manager, which I believe modifies .htaccess with basic http authentication.

Comment: @halfer This is my first time doing anything like this and if you can help me out by providing an example cron command with the new information in the question it would be much appreciated. If you need additional information please let me know. The execution time is already set in cpanel is just need the command that will execute the php script.

Comment: If you run that via the web by visiting it (e.g. `http://example.com/wp-content-stats/status.php`) and putting in the credentials, does that work? You could also try running it via PHP, do you have SSH access so you can try that? To do so, I would use the full path to the script (not the relative path that you have specified) e.g. `/home/youruser/public_html/wp-content/stats/status.php` (this is just an example, you'll need to get that from your cPanel or ask tech support for that).

Comment: @halfer Haha, I know the script will work if I visit the page in my browser, but the whole point of the cron is to let the server handle that on a schedule. I know there is a cron command that will execute the script, but I'm just not sure of the correct syntax. I thought that's what you were offering to help with.

Comment: Ah, you misunderstand my approach. By ensuring it works via the web, the fall-back approach is to use `wget` or `curl` via Cron, which I am willing to help you with. However, it is preferable (more efficient) to run the script directly without using the web server, also using cron. If you are willing to try it via SSH, and if you find that it works, that is how I would do it (this way does not involve writing your security credentials in plaintext in a config file either, which the first solution would).

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else needs the same cron command to execute a php script:

```
php -q /home/cpanelusername/public_html/path/to/your/file
```